# NullPointerException in handleStopActivity -- No reference to my code in stack trace

Tags: java, android

I'm a bit at a loss, here. I've been seeing a steadily increasing number of these `NullPointerException`s in `handleStopActivity`. I suspect that the increase coinicides with the increase in 2.2 upgrades to Droid owners, though that's just a guess. I've never seen the crash myself, and the stack trace provided by the market does not mention any of the classes I've written. As such, I have no idea where to start in fixing the problem.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity(ActivityThread.java:3674)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2600(ActivityThread.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2153)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:144)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4937)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Since I don't know the cause, I also don't know what information to provide to aid in diagnosis, so I'll give an overiew:
My app is WootWatcher. It tracks Woot.com and notifies users of new items for sale. It does this by means of a service that runs in a separate process. The service and the main activity communicate with each other via aidl interface and callback.  I also make use of message handlers in both the service and activity, and frequently spawn threads for expensive tasks.

Comment: I run droid (still no 2.2 update, waiting...)
I'll let you know if I see anything odd.

Comment: well i got the 2.2 update today and played around a little with the app.  I see no problems.

Comment: @Ben Tobin do you have any code in stop activity?

Comment: Have you tried debugging the application and to find from where this crash occurs ?

Comment: Can you post the code which is Handling the `handleStopActivity`?

Comment: I am getting same exception a lot, and have no idea what is causing it. Did anybody found the reason for that?

Comment: If my onStop code was causing the exception, wouldn't it show up in the stack trace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking back at this 4-year old question, I realize I should be able to diagnose it, but unfortunately I can't find any version of AOSP for which these lines match up. The Droid must have used some altered version of the source that wasn't made available.

That said, Froyo's `handleStopActivity()` doesn't have many opportunities for a null pointer exception. The most likely one would point to `Activity.finish()` when the Activity has already been stopped, or is in the process of being stopped.

This usually happens when you register listeners that eventually call `finish()` and you don't unregister those listeners in `onPause()`.

Answer (score 1):

How about reporting a bug to Android Project (would mandate checking if anyone else reported it) ? If no code from You is in the stack trace, that would signal a bug in the framework. Although maybe in your other code You break e.g. an unspoken contract/assumption.

Comment: Please merge your answers into one answer.

Comment: Those answers represent different approaches - why to merge them?

Comment: @KarolDepka you can create headings in it but making it a single answer is more suited to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Refer the answer in this question. Looks like a known problem and has a solution too.
Hope it helps...

[NullPointerException on onSaveInstanceState with AndroidFragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12217681/nullpointerexception-on-onsaveinstancestate-with-androidfragments)

Comment: It may be related, but this problem predated Fragments.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, if you're still looking for a solution, but here's what I found out. If you have found a real solution, please let me know.

I just had the same issue.. I never had that problem and without changing code, it appeared for some reason. By using google, I found the question that Joseph posted, but that doesn't seem to be exactly the same. I also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15074087/nullpointerexception-in-android-app-activitythread-handlestopactivity) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10322450/android-app-java-lang-nullpointerexception). These two seem to have the same issue, but no solution.. Then I found [this blog](http://www.jjoe64.com/2011/06/how-to-fix-activityperformstop.html).

The author tells something about what it's from - a bug in Android. Further, it has to do with a `Cursor`. That didn't fix my issue, but I noticed, that I used a `Cursor`, a few lines before calling `startActivity(someIntent);` (I also called `finish()`, but removing that line didn't make a difference).
I tried to remove the lines that include the `Cursor` and suddenly it works again..
I have no idea, why it works, but it does. I just moved the code with the `Cursor` to my other `Activity`.

It's definitly not a good solution, but it works for me.

There's just one more question: Do you even use a `Cursor` and call `startActivity(..)` or something similar?

**Edit:**
I just found out, that I didn't fix the problem, I just didn't test enough. The `Activity` I started was running fine until I wanted to create the next `Activity` out of that `Activity` I started before. On starting the next `Activity`, my App crashes again.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe try wrapping the method handleStopActivity in try-catch block and handle the error yourself, giving yourself more details and preventing "force-close" ?

Comment: @BenTobin you could check out what's on ActivityThread.java:3674, it can give hints sometimes. Do the bug reports on the Play Store mention the version of Android?