# Converting int to byte in Android

Tags: java, android, casting, byte, int

Actually I need to transfer the `integer` value along with the `bitmap` via `bluetooth`..  Now my problem is I need to transfer the `integer` as **single** `byte` value..
Is tat possible to **convert** `int` as **single** `byte` value.. and retrieve it as a `integer` there... I tried `byteValue()` and the **casting** thing but its not usefull.. If my approach is right just help me out with this or say some other way.

(Each time when I am using casting then it's returning as 65535)

Comment: I also tried to do with converting `int` to `char` and trying to convert as `byte` (eventhough it work for only till 255)but its not of use...

Comment: try to use serialization if you can not able to send int value directly

Comment: Why not directly use byte value and not use integer variable at all?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What about this?

```
public static byte[] intToByteArray(int a)
{
    byte[] ret = new byte[4];
    ret[3] = (byte) (a & 0xFF);   
    ret[2] = (byte) ((a >> 8) & 0xFF);   
    ret[1] = (byte) ((a >> 16) & 0xFF);   
    ret[0] = (byte) ((a >> 24) & 0xFF);
    return ret;
}
```

and

```
public static int byteArrayToInt(byte[] b)
{
    return (b[3] & 0xFF) + ((b[2] & 0xFF) << 8) + ((b[1] & 0xFF) << 16) + ((b[0] & 0xFF) << 24);
}
```

Comment: @Dante - he asked about a *single* byte.

Comment: @MByD, a single byte can not convey all the info, so I provided array to be transferred byte by byte.

Comment: @Dante: I need it in single byte.. Then i cant able to diifferentiate the `Bitmap` and the `int`

Comment: @Dante: Other answers in the sense? That casting is not at all working.. To be clear im sending the length of the bitmap along with some data.. So i need tat length in one byte.. Is tat possible..

Comment: @Dante: This the **format** im going to send via `Bluetooth` **( CHAR | CHAR | CHAR | LENGTH | BITMAP )** Now from this i have to take the length to get back the `Bitmap` in the other mobile.. Now is it clear?

Comment: @Hussain, I hope you are able to change the format. Is it possible? By the way, `char` in Java is 2 bytes.

Comment: @Dante: Yeah possible but anyway i need the `int` ie(**LENGTH**).. How to do tat..? is there any way?

Comment: @Hussain, since you are able to get `CHAR|CHAR|CHAR`, I think you can get `CHAR|CHAR|CHAR|INT`. No conversion is needed.... If my assumption is wrong (and you cannot read `INT`), then I am sure you can get `CHAR|CHAR|CHAR|CHAR|CHAR`, the last 2 `CHAR|CHAR` is the `CHAR` array of `INT`. It is similar as the conversion of `BYTE` array I showed in my answer.

Comment: @Dante: Thanks Dante i will work with tat.. Thanks for ur great help.. :)

Comment: @Hussain, if it truly works, don't forget to check my answer. XD

Comment: we can revert int like this 'ByteBuffer.wrap(byte[] ).getInt()'

Answer (score 10):

If you're completely sure, that your int variable contains a byte value [-128; 127] then it should be as simple as:

```
int i = 100; // your int variable
byte b = (byte) i;
```

Comment: Its not working while converting back to `int`.. Its returning some **default** value for every `int`

Comment: @Hussain how and when do you convert it back?

Comment: I will be passing it as a `ByteArray` thro `Bluetooth` and separate there as a `int` and other data.. With the help of **length** i will be getting the `Bitmap` available in tat..

Comment: @Hussain you'd have to post some code, your comment doesn't makes it any clearer.

Comment: The possible code i have  tried are not working.. So only i sent a comment alone... This the **format** im going to send via `Bluetooth` **( CHAR | CHAR | CHAR | LENGTH | BITMAP )** Now from this i have to take the length to get back the `Bitmap` in the other mobile..

Answer (score 2):

A single byte (8 bits) can only contain 2^8 unsigned integers, i.e [0, 255]. For signed you loose the first bit and the range becomes  [-128, 127]. If your integer fits then a simple cast should work.

Answer (score 1):

for 0-255 numbers.

```
int i = 200; // your int variable
byte b = (byte)(i & 0xFF);
```