# Converting int to byte[]

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I'm reading a value from the screen in Android and try to convert it to a byte[] to send it over Bluetooth but every time I it takes 128 from the screen, it converts it to -128 in the byte[] and than I don't get anything on the other side..What is the problem..Why is it giving negative number?..

This is the convert code :

```
ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(yourInt).array();
```

EDIT : On the other side I have to transform the byte[] to String.

And another problem..If I lower the number in the `allocate()` I get a BufferOverflowException even though I use only 1 position in the array. Why?

EDIT 2 : I'm working with 8bit numbers (0-255)

Comment: Looks like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5510319/%D0%A1onverting-int-to-byte-in-android) may help you.

Comment: you don't use only 1 position, since you put an int in a byte buffer. (reminder: an int is 4 bytes).

Comment: Yeah...That's why I was so confused...I've put a breakpoint and the array was [0,0,0,(a number)]...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    byte[] num = BigInteger.valueOf(-2147483648).toByteArray();
        System.out.println(new BigInteger(num).intValue());
    }
```

if you want to transfer only one byte, valued 0-255, then

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for(int i=0; i<=255; i++){
        byte a = (byte) i;
        byte[] num = new byte [] {(byte) a};
        System.out.println(num[0] + " : " + i + " : " + ((256+num[0]) % 256));
    }
}
```

The second code will convert a byte variable to equal integer output.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the code is doing this is because your integer (128) looks like
`1000000` in binary with a bunch of leading zeroes. Since all Java primitives are signed, the leading bit is 0 and this comes out OK. However, when you convert to bytes the leading bit gets interpreted as the sign bit, so the last `byte` is interpreted as negative.

The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#putInt(int)) is also pretty clear that `putInt()` writes all 4 bytes of the integer to the buffer, instead of only the bytes which are "used".

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing the correct values in the ByteBuffer. The last byte of the buffer has the byte value 0x80, which if you sign extend to a longer int value APPEARS as -128 when displaying in a dumb terminal.

```
BYTE VALUES
1000 0000
```

This hight bit typically designates a negative number in signed byte/short/int systems.

If you convert this signed byte to a larger type like an int by just prepending 1 bits, you would see this:

```
1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1000 0000
```

Which indicates -128 as a signed int.