# NullPointerException on onSaveInstanceState with AndroidFragments

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-fragments

I am receiving a NullPointerException when I LEAVE a FragmentActivity and go to a ListActivity.  I actually start to see the list before I get the Force Close.  But the LogCat refers to the Activity that I just came from.

The LogCat says this:

```
08-31 07:38:53.356: E/AndroidRuntime(8134): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-31 07:38:53.356: E/AndroidRuntime(8134): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-31 07:38:53.356: E/AndroidRuntime(8134):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.saveFragmentBasicState(FragmentManager.java:1576)
08-31 07:38:53.356: E/AndroidRuntime(8134):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.saveAllState(FragmentManager.java:1617)
08-31 07:38:53.356: E/AndroidRuntime(8134):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onSaveInstanceState(FragmentActivity.java:481)
08-31 07:38:53.356: E/AndroidRuntime(8134):     at com.---.myApp.MasterCat.onSaveInstanceState(MasterCat.java:119)
08-31 07:38:53.356: E/AndroidRuntime(8134):     at android.app.Activity.performSaveInstanceState(Activity.java:1137)
08-31 07:38:53.356: E/AndroidRuntime(8134):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnSaveInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1215)
08-31 07:38:53.356: E/AndroidRuntime(8134):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:3077)
08-31 07:38:53.356: E/AndroidRuntime(8134):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity(ActivityThread.java:3136)
08-31 07:38:53.356: E/AndroidRuntime(8134):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:142)
08-31 07:38:53.356: E/AndroidRuntime(8134):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1235)
08-31 07:38:53.356: E/AndroidRuntime(8134):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-31 07:38:53.356: E/AndroidRuntime(8134):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-31 07:38:53.356: E/AndroidRuntime(8134):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4928)
08-31 07:38:53.356: E/AndroidRuntime(8134):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-31 07:38:53.356: E/AndroidRuntime(8134):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-31 07:38:53.356: E/AndroidRuntime(8134):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
08-31 07:38:53.356: E/AndroidRuntime(8134):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:558)
08-31 07:38:53.356: E/AndroidRuntime(8134):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Line 119 in MasterCat is:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

I am not sure what other code to show, please let me know.  My basic setup contains 4 static inner classes that are all fragments inside the parent `FragmentActivity` (using the support library).  It uses tabs and a viewpager.

EDIT, More Code:

```
public class MasterCat extends FragmentActivity implements
        ActionBar.TabListener {

    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_layout);
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(
                getSupportFragmentManager());
        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
        mViewPager
                .setOnPageChangeListener(
                    new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                        actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
                    }
                });
        for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
                    .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                    .setTabListener(this));
        }
    }

    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {}

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {}

    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            Fragment f = null;
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
            {
                f = new MasterFrag();
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                f.setArguments(args);
                break;
            }
            case 1:
            {
                f = new FeaturedFrag();
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                f.setArguments(args);
                break;
            }
            case 2:
            {
                f = new TopFrag();
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                f.setArguments(args);
                break;
            }
            case 3:
            {
                f = new NewFrag();
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                f.setArguments(args);
                break;
            }
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("not this many fragments: "
                    + position);
            }
            return f;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 4;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return getString(R.string.mastercattab1).toUpperCase();
            case 1:
                return getString(R.string.mastercattab2).toUpperCase();
            case 2:
                return getString(R.string.mastercattab3).toUpperCase();
            case 3:
                return getString(R.string.mastercattab4).toUpperCase();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

A Typical Fragment has an outline like this:

```
public static class FeaturedFrag extends Fragment {

    public FeaturedFrag() {}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.rateithome, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

Comment: put your activity and fragment codes too

Comment: @Waqas Just added lots more code per request.

Comment: is there a previous error message before the one you posted?

Comment: This was the only error message that I know of.  I just discovered (and it make sense) same things happens by simply pressing the home button.  So leaving this FragmentActivity to ANY WHERE causes the crash.

Comment: isn't there a way to check if its null before leaving? such as `if (savedInstanceState == null) { `

Comment: It looks like it might be a [bug in the Android support library](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/actionbarsherlock/B3QOI3j2DPo).  Try replacing the `android-support-v4.jar` in the libs folder with the latest one from the SDK Manager.

Comment: @theisenp I updated it to the newest version in my SDK Manager, do I have to replace the file in the app now?

Comment: Yes, I would try replacing the `android-support-v4.jar` in the libs folder with the latest one from the SDK Manager.

Comment: @theisenp Go ahead and write that as an answer because you just fixed my issue!

Comment: Great! I've added the solution as an answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It looks like this is a [known bug in the Android Support Library](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/actionbarsherlock/B3QOI3j2DPo/lpEFbjODWkEJ).  Fortunately, it's been patched.

To fix the bug:

1. Use the SDK Manager to update to the latest version of the support library
2. Replace the `android-support-v4.jar` file in your application's `libs/` folder with the new version that you just downloaded

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

if (savedInstanceState != null) 
   {
      super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }
 }
```

Comment: This didn't work.  It still goes right past the condition as if it is NOT null and trips up on the same line "super.onSave...".  Someone said it might be a bug with the support library; so I am trying to work that out now as my next option.

Comment: Well I simply updated the support library - there was a bug in it.  All is well now.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a quick **workaround**, add this to your Fragment code:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    // Workaround to avoid NPE from support library bug:
    setUserVisibleHint(false);

    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

The `setUserVisibleHint` property is indeed just a hint for optimization and shouldn't cause you any trouble, see [Android reference documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#setUserVisibleHint%28boolean%29).

Of course, updating the Support library as [answered by theisenp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12219557/2560665) might be more desirable in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have used this style AppTheme.NoActionBar

in manifest file
and in java class ,you are using actionbar that's why it cause crashes.

Can you show me your manifest file and style.xml