# App crashes on super.onSaveInstanceState

Tags: android, crash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [NullPointerException on onSaveInstanceState with AndroidFragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12217681/nullpointerexception-on-onsaveinstancestate-with-androidfragments)

when I call super.onSaveInstanceState I get a 
NullPointerException 
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.saveFragmentBasicState(FragmentManager.java:1542)
on some devices, some others work.

```
 public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            //...
            super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }
```

With Android 4.1 on a Nexus Tablet its working, on a Samsung with Android 4.0 not. What is the problem here and how can I solve it?  Uncommenting onSaveInstanceState works, but I dont think this is correct and it makes my app behave incorrect somewhere else.

Thanks
Marvin

edit
added stacktrace

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.saveFragmentBasicState(FragmentManager.java:1542)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.saveAllState(FragmentManager.java:1572)
    at android.app.Activity.onSaveInstanceState(Activity.java:1164)
    at com.MApp.MActivity.onSaveInstanceState(MActivity.java:1111)
    at android.app.Activity.performSaveInstanceState(Activity.java:1113)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnSaveInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1188)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3337)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:127)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1163)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4507)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Ca you provide a stacktrace with the exception you get?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles

Comment: i have added the stacktrace

Answer (score 3):

Ok I figured it out now.
This is because my fragment had no
`onSaveInstanceState`

I had to fill the bundle with dummy values.
It's a bug in android in version 4.0. However, I don't know about other versions.

Comment: Its a bug in the compatibility library too.