# how to work with simple button in actionbarsherlock in android?

Tags: java, android, actionbarsherlock

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragment;

public class Fragment_1  extends SherlockFragment{

     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_1,
                 container, false);
         ImageView button = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
         button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

             @Override
             public void onClick(View arg0) {
                 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Temp.class);
                 getActivity().startActivity(intent);
             }
         });

         return view;
     }



}
```

I am trying to move from fragment activity to normal activity but its showing activity page i.e hello world written on it but suddenly its getting unfortunately stop. can you please help me. I am trying to make it work from past 3 days but not able to figure it out what actually is the problem. Even I checked thousand times the android manifest file .i.e.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.project.paul"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.project.paul.Splash"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.project.paul.Login"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.project.paul.Option"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_option"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Actionstyle" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.project.paul.Fragment_1"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_option"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Actionstyle" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.project.paul.Fragment_2"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_option"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Actionstyle" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.project.paul.ImageOptions" 
            >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.project.paul.Temp"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_temp" 
             >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I will be thankful if you help me out with my problem.

logcat errors :

06-29 22:26:43.647: E/AndroidRuntime(773): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-29 22:26:43.647: E/AndroidRuntime(773): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-29 22:26:43.647: E/AndroidRuntime(773):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.saveFragmentBasicState(FragmentManager.java:1576)
06-29 22:26:43.647: E/AndroidRuntime(773):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.saveAllState(FragmentManager.java:1617)
06-29 22:26:43.647: E/AndroidRuntime(773):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onSaveInstanceState(FragmentActivity.java:481)
06-29 22:26:43.647: E/AndroidRuntime(773):  at android.app.Activity.performSaveInstanceState(Activity.java:1147)
06-29 22:26:43.647: E/AndroidRuntime(773):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnSaveInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1216)
06-29 22:26:43.647: E/AndroidRuntime(773):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:3129)
06-29 22:26:43.647: E/AndroidRuntime(773):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity(ActivityThread.java:3188)
06-29 22:26:43.647: E/AndroidRuntime(773):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:141)
06-29 22:26:43.647: E/AndroidRuntime(773):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1261)
06-29 22:26:43.647: E/AndroidRuntime(773):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-29 22:26:43.647: E/AndroidRuntime(773):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-29 22:26:43.647: E/AndroidRuntime(773):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
06-29 22:26:43.647: E/AndroidRuntime(773):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-29 22:26:43.647: E/AndroidRuntime(773):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-29 22:26:43.647: E/AndroidRuntime(773):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-29 22:26:43.647: E/AndroidRuntime(773):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-29 22:26:43.647: E/AndroidRuntime(773):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-29 22:26:48.096: E/Trace(793): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)

Comment: plz provide log cat error

Comment: @SyedZahidAli I am posting my error below

Comment: @SyedZahidAli if you have any suggestion or examples .. it will be a help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this thread, It may help, if not then I'll post my code

[NullPointerException on onSaveInstanceState with AndroidFragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12217681/nullpointerexception-on-onsaveinstancestate-with-androidfragments)