# App crashes onPause

Tags: android, android-fragments, crash

I've made a soundboard application. I'm using SherlockActionBar for fragments. When I swipe to another fragment and than press the home button my application crashes.

I'm not overriding `onSaveInstanceState`, `onPause`, `onDestroy`, etc.

The problem still exists even if I delete all my fragment content

`My Log:`

```
09-16 19:33:57.030: E/AndroidRuntime(32080): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-16 19:33:57.030: E/AndroidRuntime(32080): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pause activity {com.mega.sb/com.mega.sb.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-16 19:33:57.030: E/AndroidRuntime(32080):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2879)
09-16 19:33:57.030: E/AndroidRuntime(32080):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2835)
09-16 19:33:57.030: E/AndroidRuntime(32080):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2813)
09-16 19:33:57.030: E/AndroidRuntime(32080):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:140)
09-16 19:33:57.030: E/AndroidRuntime(32080):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1238)
09-16 19:33:57.030: E/AndroidRuntime(32080):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-16 19:33:57.030: E/AndroidRuntime(32080):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-16 19:33:57.030: E/AndroidRuntime(32080):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
09-16 19:33:57.030: E/AndroidRuntime(32080):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-16 19:33:57.030: E/AndroidRuntime(32080):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-16 19:33:57.030: E/AndroidRuntime(32080):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
09-16 19:33:57.030: E/AndroidRuntime(32080):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
09-16 19:33:57.030: E/AndroidRuntime(32080):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-16 19:33:57.030: E/AndroidRuntime(32080): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-16 19:33:57.030: E/AndroidRuntime(32080):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.saveFragmentBasicState(FragmentManager.java:1576)
09-16 19:33:57.030: E/AndroidRuntime(32080):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.saveAllState(FragmentManager.java:1617)
09-16 19:33:57.030: E/AndroidRuntime(32080):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onSaveInstanceState(FragmentActivity.java:481)
09-16 19:33:57.030: E/AndroidRuntime(32080):    at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity.onSaveInstanceState(SherlockFragmentActivity.java:126)
09-16 19:33:57.030: E/AndroidRuntime(32080):    at android.app.Activity.performSaveInstanceState(Activity.java:1181)
09-16 19:33:57.030: E/AndroidRuntime(32080):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnSaveInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1219)
09-16 19:33:57.030: E/AndroidRuntime(32080):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2861)
09-16 19:33:57.030: E/AndroidRuntime(32080):    ... 12 more
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: post your code here..and specify in what line you are getting the error...(null pointer in your case)

Comment: Which version of the support library are you running on?

Comment: Where do I get the version of the support library?

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12217681/nullpointerexception-on-onsaveinstancestate-with-androidfragments

Comment: Will try that, thanks,, will report back

Comment: setRetainInstance(true)

Comment: I now get 'Jar mismatch, fix your dependencies'

Comment: @Henkie You have two versions of the support jar. Update them both to the latest version.

Comment: Updated them both, yet the problem still is there

Comment: @Henkie, refresh the workspace, clean and rebuild.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

changing the `FragmentPagerAdapter` to `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` should do the trick!

Answer (score 0):

Try this workaround :

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) 
{
    outState.putString("your_key", "your_value");           
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

Its a bug of sorts (or maybe not). But try the above For all fragments, override the `onSaveInstanceState()` as given above

**One more thing your libs also can contradict so you have to use same libs for `android-support-v4.jar` for both (your project and for SherlockActionBar Library)**